# Mapped typed within mapped type generic does work, except it doesnt

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

[Here is the ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkBdQdwewE4GsDOAaUAjArtAKgJ4AOApigMYICWR0VKo2AdgBYCGRRBAUJMSaAC2bJCQDKiSAHlaVOExQAePKBIAPSCSYATBgCUS5RNsUAiNgBscglKdAAfUKcgI25VKYwoXVJgHMAPgDQAF5QAG9uUFAAbVECUF9QeLgAM1A8AF0ALgjYgDdLbAEkvDiSAkycpzYKLW1fPztHU20ycnrGuwBfbl7eflAJBGlZeQYw4VFh0cg5BUUoiKXoy2sUXOcqSAsSUxXQFzdUTbmdvYcakfpIfejegO5uECHJGTnxxIY0w5YBdVI5E02kO-GeYBw0BgLAS9Ay-Ao1FojFYHC4sG2LF%20AlwVAsFm2CT4pAA-NwjApoGpcjN3vMJstVlZsDZcuFDttdps2nUdF1QN00Esju4NozoqA2NdvNz2p1-J4DmcuTVeQ0FUL7kL%20i8ACJwMiShgAwzA0BMOBQxBIcnjaAEGlvMYKULitYssXs5UkTYoIhuARsHQcwQXQWgYWuUVsg5SuYypypOBwRUSrBSza1Dp8jVLQV9bhAA)

I want to create a type, which creates an object out of the keys of a `given object`, with the values being another object created out of the union type of the `given object`.

```
// It works, but Typescript is unhappy
type makeSortOptions<T extends Record<"albums" | "tracks", string>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: { [value in T[key]]: "ascending" | "descending" }
}

type SortOptions = makeSortOptions<
  {
    albums: "title"
    tracks: "title" | "artist"
  }
>

// SortOptions is of the expected type
// but why is Typescript unhappy with the utillity type?
const x: SortOptions = {
  albums: { title: "descending" },
  tracks: {
    artist: "descending",
    title: "ascending",
  },
}

// Does as expected not work
const y: SortOptions = {
  albums: { title: "space and time" }, 
  tracks: {
    artist: "foo",
    bar: "ascending",
  },
}
```

And that is the error I am getting:

```
Type 'T[key]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is not happy because `T[key]` could theoratically be a type which is not `string`, `number` or `symbol`.

Imagine this call:

```
type SortOptions = makeSortOptions<
  {
    albums: "title"
    tracks: "title" | "artist"
    zzz: { a: 123 }
  }
>
```

It is totally valid to call `makeSortOptions` with this object, but the `zzz` property contains an *object* which can not be used as a *key*.

---

I would put the valid `Keys` in an extra type.

```
type Keys = "albums" | "tracks"

type makeSortOptions<T extends Record<Keys, string>> = {
  [key in Keys]: { [value in T[key]]: "ascending" | "descending" }
}
```

Instead of mapping over `keyof T` (which could lead to non-keyable types), we map over `Keys`. And through the constraint `T extends Record<Keys, string>`, TypeScript knows that every key of `Keys` must lead to a `string` type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkBdQdwewE4GsDOAaUAjArtAKgJ4AOApigMYICWR0VKo2AdgBYCGRRBAUN5MSVABpEgQYBeUACI2AGxwBbFFNAAfaZARtyqKb36lQCtkhIBlRJADytKnCYoAPHlAkAHpBJMAJgwBKJOSI3o4iYhgomlRMAOYAfHGgkgDe3KCgANqmBKDRwqIoALoAXKDJmQBuctiCeXhZooUl0mwUXt7RMSrqUt5k5O2dKgC%203KN8AqAWCNa29hJGJuaWNpB2Do5pZVvpcooopVJrkLIkeunpmtqoh8en3S0z9JDnFwBeH6XlbKUAjABMAGZQKN0qM4rwQFMVnMHLkGHAAGagSAsQTuUjkTzeFECbhQnDQGAsHL0UCEUgUai0RisDhcWBUVEotGMNayWRMnIGEgAfm4QQc0DcpWmszW8yS2128mwSi%20KKZp0OfTaPiGILQWyuOgO0oubCekRV-UGsSkWouipOJEOrQG6vNls1Y0hYAAInAyKBWq43JjsaAmHAiYgkAL5tACKKYRK4Sktns5XryndbdIUERtII2D5FQozprQNqtLqvjsfUbIIdEXA4BaK5hDXa1R0nVthlrRkA)

---

You could also just intersect it with a `string`.

```
type makeSortOptions<T extends Record<"albums" | "tracks", string>> = {
  [key in keyof T]: { [value in T[key] & string]: "ascending" | "descending" }
}
```

Non-`string` types would then evaluate to `never` and would not show up in the type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEkBdQdwewE4GsDOAaUAjArtAKgJ4AOApigMYICWR0VKo2AdgBYCGRRBAUJMSaAC2bJCQDKiSAHlaVOExQAePKBIAPSCSYATBgCUS5RNsUAiNgBscglKdAAfUKcgI25VKYwoXVJgHMAPgDQAF5QAG9uUFAAbVECUF9QeLgAM1A8AF0ALgjYgDdLbAEkvDiSAkzQADJQb2p-HKc2Ci1tXz87R1NtMnI2jrsAX24R3n5QCQRpWXkGMOFRKZnIOQVFKIjN6MtrFFznKkgLElNt0Bc3VAPV49OHZun6SDPokYDubhBJyRlVucSDDSFxYAnUpHImm0F34XzAOGgMBYCXoGX4FGotEYrA4XFgRxYIIEuCoFgsRwSfFIAH5uEYFNA1Llln81vMtjsrNgbLlwhcjicDr1WjpBqAhmhNpd3PsOdFQGwnt4hX0Bv5POdboLmiL2urJW9JWNvgAROBkBUMcGGKGgJhwRGIJB0ubQAjM36zBShOW7bmyvlakgHFBENwCNg6fmCe4S0BS1wy3nnRWrZVOVJwOAa%20VYRUHFr9UX6zYS0bcIA)

Comment: Thank you for help. One question though: Is `T extends Record<"albums" | "tracks", string>` nit specifying that all keys should be of type string? Your provided invalid call does not get accepted by TS as it does not fit the constrains.

Comment: Oddly enough, the playground accepts the invalid call, but my editor does not, stating that it does not meet the constrain Record<"...", string>

Comment: @Woww - Yeah it is not invalid. `T extends Record<"albums" | "tracks", string>` only specifies that those two keys must be `string`. But everything else is allowed.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you :) - Wait, but why does this behaviour change when I put the keys into their own union type?

Comment: @Woww - When we map over `keyof T`, TypeScript considers all possibilities which also means that a key of `T` might have a non-string type. Hence the error. But when we map over the keys directly (by hard coding them in a separate string union type), TypeScript can be sure that `T[key]` must be a string.